# Reading a 'Location' header from a System.Net.Http.HttpContent object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am having trouble reading the `Location` header from parts of a multipart response of an http request. I am using `HttpClient`, and processing the resultant `HttpResponseMessage` (mostly) as follows:

```
protected internal virtual async Task ProcessMultiPartResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var multipart = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(multipart.Contents.Select(ProccessContentAsync));
}

protected async Task ProccessContentAsync(HttpContent content)
{
    var location = content.Headers.GetValues("Location").FirstOrDefault(); //nada
    //...
}
```

---

I have verified the `Location` header is actually in the response using fiddler:

[image: Fiddler Screenshot]

---

And that the other headers are being read successfully:

[image: Successful headers]

---

From inspecting the non-public property `headers.invalidHeaders` I see `Location` listed, as shown below, which seems suspect to me...

[image: Invalid Headers]

Is that my problem? If so how can I get around it. If not what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: What is the http status code?

Comment: @zespri Status code is 200 OK

Comment: My suspicion is that Location header is not a valid header for this status code. It should be either 201 or 3xx.

Comment: Yea, I don't doubt that its not. Unfortunately I don't control this API. Its part of the RETS (yes rets, not rest) spec

Comment: Well, then you need an http client that can tolerate that. It appears that the one that you are using (the standard one) adheres to standards and does not tolerate it.